# Relationship between Eisenstein series $E_2$ and Eisenstein series $G_2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, elliptic-functions

One can find two series called *Eisenstein series of weight 2*. The first one is
$$
E_2(\tau) = 1 - 24 \sum_{n\geqslant 1}\frac{n q^{2n}}{1-q^{2n}} \quad \textrm{with } \; q=\exp(i\pi\tau)
$$
and the second one is
$$
G_2(\tau)=\sum_{c\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum_{d\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1_{(c,d)\ne (0,0)}}{(c\tau+d)^2}.
$$
What is the link between these two series? I thought this is
$$
G_2 = \frac{\pi^2}{3} E_2,
$$
but that does not fit to my numerical checks.

Comment: One of them is an explicit multiple of the other. Compute $\int_0^1{G_2(x+iy)e^{-2i\pi nx}\,dx}$ and expand $\frac{q^{2n}}{1-q^{2n}}=\sum_{p\geq 1}{q^{2np}}$. The standard notation is $q=e^{2i\pi\tau}$.

Comment: @Aphelli. Thanks. But I don't see how to calculate this integral. I didn't practice mathematics for a couple of years or even more...

Comment: I’ve been thinking for a little bit – computing the integral shouldn’t be the easiest way actually… the key point is that (with your notations) $i\frac{q^2+1}{q^2-1}=i\frac{q+1/q}{q-1/q}=\pi\mathrm{cot}(\pi\tau)=\sum_{d \in \mathbb{Z}}{\frac{1}{\tau+d}}$ (the last equality is highly nontrivial – you can show it by noting that the difference is holomorphic outside $\mathbb{Z}$ and $1$-periodic, vanishing at zero, and bounded away from the real axis, so it’s bounded holomorphic, so constant, so zero). Then differentiate and sum over all $c\tau$ with $c\geq 1$ and $\tau$ in the upper half-plane.

Comment: But there’s no easy way to prove this identity – it’s always technically involved. A complete derivation should be in most texts about *modular forms*.

Comment: @Aphelli. Thanks. I'm not highly interested in the derivation. I'm currently working on an implementation of Weierstrass elliptic functions and related functions, and I just want the result. But I will try to follow your hints.

Comment: Yes, $G_2$ should be $\frac{\pi^2}{3}E_2$, actually… at least when the imaginary part of $\tau$ is positive…

Comment: @Aphelli. Arrggh... if this result is true, there are some issues in my computer program :-(

Comment: @Aphelli. I checked numerically, and $\frac{\pi^2}{3}E_2$ works only for $\tau$ purely imaginary.

Comment: That doesn’t look right. Both series are holomorphic so such an equality means that it should hold everywhere…

Comment: Please show us your code. There is probably an easy error involved. The Wikipedia article [Eisenstein series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series) states that the summation definition is **only** valid for $G_4$ and above.

Comment: @Somos Sorry this works actually. This can be seen by taking a small real part. Otherwise, the convergence is too slow, that's why I thought it didn't work.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Did you read the beginning of the Wikipedia article where It states "Define the holomorphic Eisenstein series $\,G_{2k}(\tau)\,$ of weight $2k$, where $k\ge 2$ is an integer, by the following series: "? Note carefully the $k\ge 2$.

Comment: @Somos Yes, I saw that. But I swear it works for $k = 1$, otherwise my computer program would not give correct results.

Comment: Then what is the point of your question if your program gives "correct results"?

Comment: @Somos I posted this question because I thought the equality is not true. I realized it is true only when discussing with Aphelli.